# Программирование математических множеств

Tags: математика, множества

Всем Привет!

Занимаюсь индексированием данных из файлов. Пришёл к выводу, что необходима библиотека для работы с математическими множествами. Есть идея написать самому или найти готовую, но не могу сообразить, куда копать. Подскажите, есть ли такой раздел (библиотека) в программировании и как он называется.
Язык любой, хорошо, если есть языки с нативной поддержкой мат. множеств.

Теперь попробую объяснить, чего же я хочу.

Скрипт индексирует изделия из таблиц. Изделия имеют название и некоторый набор свойств (набор может различаться для каждого изделия). Например, габариты изделия - три параметра, которые являются частью трёх множеств x, y, z, которые в свою очередь составляют множество размеров. Похоже на обычные коллекции из nosql, но в nosql нет вложенных множеств (или есть?).
Сами изделия, в свою очередь, могут попадать в различные множества (изделия, на которые выдан паспорт, сертификат, проданный, списанный, имеет срок годности); одно изделие может состоять из нескольких изделий.
Т.е., всё как в жизни (в том числе допуски на погрешности и среднеквадратичное отклонение для нахождение ошибок).

Comment: Как по мне - попахивает чрезмерным формализмом. Тот же JSON сможет хранить всю необходимую информацию об изделии.

Comment: Не могу с Вами не согласиться. Да, всё можно запрограммировать в одной записи: и свойства, и ссылки. Просто, может кто-то уже занимался этим вопросом, чтобы можно было изучить труды и вновь не изобретать велосипед. Я, например, не могу сообразить, как зашифровать те же ссылки на другие записи...

Comment: Практически во всех высокоуровневых языках есть абстракции для работы с множествами. Но если вам нужны «нечёткие» множества (то есть, ваше отношение равенства нетранзитивно), вам, боюсь, придётся либо искать специальную библиотеку, либо программировать самому.

Comment: @Stan ссылки на другие запись - по ID записи, как это в SQL делается.